# First Letter Check Similarity

Tags: java

*What the program should do:*

- The program is to see if two words have the same starting letter.

I was wondering if someone could help with the debugging of this program.

I think I did everything right but the program is coming up as an error when I try to run it.

I don't see what could be wrong. Maybe my print class at the bottom but other than that I don't see anything wrong.

```
    import static java.lang.System.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class StringFirstLetterCheck
    {
            String wordOne, wordTwo;

            public StringFirstLetterCheck()
            {
            }

            public StringFirstLetterCheck(String one, String two)
            {
                    wordOne = one;
                    wordTwo = two;
            }

            public void setWords(String one, String two)
            {
                    wordOne = one;
                    wordTwo = two;
            }

            public boolean checkFirstLetter( )
            {
                    if (wordOne.charAt(0)== wordTwo.charAt(0));

                    return true;


            }

            public String toString()
            {
                    if (wordOne.charAt(0)!= wordTwo.charAt(0))
                            return wordOne + " does not have the same first letter as " + wordTwo + "\n";

                    else if (wordOne.charAt(0)== wordTwo.charAt(0))
                            return wordOne + " does not have same first letter as " + wordTwo + "\n";

                    return ("wrong");
            }

            public static void main( String args[] )
            {
                    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                    out.print("Enter word one :: ");
                    String a = keyboard.nextLine();
                    out.print("Enter word two ::");
                    String b = keyboard.nextLine();
                    StringFirstLetterCheck test = new                StringFirstLetterCheck ();
                    out.print(test);
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
   at StringFirstLetterCheck.toString(StringFirstLetterCheck.java:41) 
   at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) 
   at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source) 
   at StringFirstLetterCheck.main(StringFirstLetterCheck.java:58)
```

Comment: Why don't you help us help you by adding the text of the error you say you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at StringFirstLetterCheck.toString(StringFirstLetterCheck.java:41)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
 at StringFirstLetterCheck.main(StringFirstLetterCheck.java:58)

Comment: I just saw a mistake it doesn't fix anything but the else if should say "does have the same first letter as"

Comment: Next time: (1) please include the error in your question, instead of making us ask for it.  This really should be obvious.  Why would you ask us to help you with "an error" without telling us what the error is?  Also, it's much better to put it in the question, where it's more readable, than in a comment.  (2) If the error is a stack trace that includes line numbers, please point out what lines have those line numbers, so that we don't have to use our fingers to count.  You probably already have the info easily if you're using an IDE.

Comment: Alright thank you for the advice I will make sure to do so next time

Comment: I would say that you should start from this post. Use [edit] option and make this question answerable (without having to read other comments). Also post full code which is needed to reproduce your problem. Your current code will not even compile.

Comment: A better way to `checkFirstLetter()` is `return Character.toUpperCase(wordOne.charAt(0)) == Character.toUpperCase(wordTwo.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor for the `StringFirstLetterCheck` object is missing the parameters to set the `wordOne` and `wordTwo` instance variables. Instead it should be ...

```
StringFirstLetterCheck test = new StringFirstLetterCheck (a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you create the object using the default constructor..

```
StringFirstLetterCheck test = new StringFirstLetterCheck ();
```

And then you attempt to print out the object, which automatically called the `toString` method. This method doesn't validate the fields, so it is throwing your `NullPointerException`. The fix for this is to use the proper constructor and pass in the correct values.

```
StringFirstLetterCheck test = new StringFirstLetterCheck (a, b);
```

**Other Notes**

As Jaskaranbir has pointed out, your if statement syntax is incorrect. I would go further and say you can simply return the boolean expression.

```
return wordOne.charAt(0) == wordTwo.charAt(0);
```

Additionally, you've got a method to check if the words match, so you can recall that method, rather than copying the code in the `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the right constructor as follows:

StringFirstLetterCheck test = new StringFirstLetterCheck (a,b);

Also, :-)

```
    else if (wordOne.charAt(0)== wordTwo.charAt(0))
        return wordOne + " **have same** first letter as " + wordTwo + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

More things that are wrong in this code:

1. The method `checkFirstLetter` has a typo. There's a semi-colon at
   the end of the if statement that means the if is ignored and the
   method would always return true.
2. The methods `checkFirstLetter` and
   `setWords` are never used, they should be delete.